# Why is SFDX is removing negative permissions from PermissionSets?

Tags: salesforcedx, permission-sets

I have recently observed two different behaviors from SFDX when fetching a Permission Set.  Initially (last week) I had to pull a permission set from a Sandbox into an SFDX project, using `sfdx force:source:retrieve -m 'PermissionSet:Permission_Set_Name'`.  This worked fine, although I had to remove a few permissions for objects/fields that only exist in the sandbox (not in the DX project source) to get a working scratch build (not uncommon).

But yesterday I had to pull some changes from the sandbox, again using `sfdx force:source:retrieve`.  In addition to the expected changes, the retrieve removed all `<fieldPermissions>` elements for which both `<editable>` and `<readable>` were false.  This is probably fine for building scratch orgs, since any field not explicitly listed will default to no read/no edit anyway, but it could cause an issue if we were removing previously granted FLS and needed to push the updated permission set into another org.

But my primary concern is understanding why two `retrieve` operations runs days apart gave two different behaviors (including or excluding non-permissioned fields).  I found [a comment on a cli github issue](https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/343) that suggested the difference in behavior could be due to API version, but this project has been on api 48 for months.  I searched the release notes for Spring 20 as well as the [CLI Release notes](https://developer.salesforce.com/media/salesforce-cli/releasenotes.html) anyway, but I could not find any documentation of this as a change.  I know that fetching Profiles with DX or MDAPI can yield different results depending on what else is fetched concurrently, but a) I don't think permission sets do the same; b) I'm pretty sure that each time I've fetched only the permission set; c) it's all `fieldPermissions`.

Does there exist any definitive documentation about how permission sets should work with DX, especially when/why non-permissioned fields would be omitted, and if this is configurable at all?

**Edit to add:** I'm now seeing a similar issue with UserPermissions in a profile; a recent pull removed negative UserPermissions such as RunReports:

```
-    <userPermissions>
-        <enabled>false</enabled>
-        <name>RunReports</name>
-    </userPermissions>
```

This is definitely breaking things.  Why is this occurring?